# Coding a simulation model

Tags: java, simulation

I have to do this simulation model but I don't know how to start it and where to start it. i asked my supervisor about this , he also not have a clue about this. so I'm asking your opinion.
Here is what I have to do.

- I have to simulate GSM signal strength from area to area in a simple map model.
- I have to show the user location and when changing the user location from one place to another which tower gives the mobile client the GSM signals it require

I'm not asking to code this or something guys, I'm just asking to show me the way to do this?
Any tutorials regarding this, your knowledge to sort out the things would be very helpful.

I have a knowledge in Java also.

Regards,
Rangana

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a simulation, it can be faked quite easily (unless I'm misunderstanding what's required).

Create your map model in whichever format you need to. This might be using Google/Bing maps API, or a custom map.

Create a list of GPS coordinates and traverse through them to simulate the user moving around the map.

Calculate the distance between the user and each tower (could use the Euclidean distance) and determine the strength of the the GSM at an given point. I'm not going to explain how you could calculate such a value, but it should be pretty easy.

Without more specific information, it's pretty difficult to give any more detail. Is this part of a university project?

Comment: thank you for the quick response. yes this is a university project. i have to simulate how a mobile phone switches from tower to tower. i get basic idea about what you say. how can we create a list of GPS coordinates and traverse through them?

Comment: It's your uni project, so you should be looking into it yourself ;) Think about the different data structures available in Java that would be suited to holding a group of objects. Each collection will have it's own way of being traversed. How you get your GPS information is up to you. If you have a device you need to use, then it'll have its own API, otherwise you could just manually type in the coordinates.